# How to open browser instance with my bookmarks and settings using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I use the brave browser as my default browser but I was wondering if it is possible to open up my regular browser profile when I run my code instead of the new instance where it does not have all my bookmarks and passwords?

Thanks in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import datetime

day = datetime.datetime.now()
dag = day.weekday()
def Testing():
    if dag >= 5:
        return Weekend()
    else:
        return Weekday()


def Weekend():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    ## options.add_argument("/Users/vadim/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser")
    options.binary_location = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
    driver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
    driver.get('https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox')
    Outlook_Aanmelden = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div/aside/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a')
    Outlook_Aanmelden.click()
    Email_Field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0116"]')
    Email_Field.send_keys('@live.com')
    Outlook_Volgende = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    Outlook_Volgende.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Password_Field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]')
    Password_Field.send_keys('pass')
    Password_Field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    Inlog_Outlook = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    Inlog_Outlook.click()

    driver.execute_script("window.open('https://youtube.com');")

def Weekday():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    ## options.add_argument("/Users/vadim/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser")
    options.binary_location = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
    driver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
    driver.get('https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox')
    Outlook_Aanmelden = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div/aside/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a')
    Outlook_Aanmelden.click()
    Email_Field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0116"]')
    Email_Field.send_keys('@live.com')
    Outlook_Volgende = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    Outlook_Volgende.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Password_Field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]')
    Password_Field.send_keys('pass')
    Password_Field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    Inlog_Outlook = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    Inlog_Outlook.click()

    driver.execute_script("window.open('https://youtube.com');")

Testing()
```

So yeah been having this problem for some time now and haven't found anyone who seems to know the solution just yet, maybe you can help me out?

Comment: My first question is why do you want your bookmarks? and saved passwords?

Comment: I basically want to automize my morning routing of opening my browser with my college schedule, mail etc. and I'd like to have my bookmarks and stuff there so I can continue browsing after I checked those main sites.

Comment: Selenium might not be the tool you want for this. I'm not familiar with using Brave browser but chrome (you're using chrome driver) allows you to specify a user profile to launch with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your `chrome` with the user profile, like so. Assuming it is chrome and not brave.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=<path to chrome profile>') 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

The location for Chrome’s default profile folder differs depending on your platform. The locations are:

```
Windows 7, 8.1, and 10: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Mac OS X El Capitan: Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default

Linux: /home/<username>/.config/google-chrome/default
```